# Why won't my quick sort work

Tags: c++, sorting

I can't figure out why this code isn't quite correct. It sorts most of the array, but some numbers are out of place. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
int partition(int* an_array, int from, int to)
{
    int pivot = an_array[(from + to) / 2];
    int left = from;   
    int right = to;   
    while(left < right)
    {
        while(an_array[left] < pivot)
        {
            left = left + 1; 
        }//end while loop       
        while(an_array[right] > pivot)
        {
            right = right - 1; 
        }//end while
        if(left < right)
        {
            swap_numbers(an_array[left], an_array[right]);
            left = left + 1; 
            right = right - 1; 
        }//end if 
    }//end while loop
    return right; 
}//end partition function 


void quick_sort(int* an_array, int from, int to)
{
    if(from >= to) return; 
    int p = partition(an_array, from, to); 
    quick_sort(an_array, from, p); 
    quick_sort(an_array, p + 1, to); 
}//end quick_sort
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug it?  What do you think the problem is?  What specifically is going wrong?  Please provide more detail so that we can help out.

Comment: I've tagged your question with C, since that's what it looks like. Feel free to re-tag if I'm wrong. This makes it more likely that the right audience will see your question. I will second the first comment: What specifically is going wrong ?

Comment: Just call `qsort`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: When you're trying to learn data structures, and you have to implement these things for a class, there is a need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I would find the smallest array on which the sort fails (hopefully quite small) and then just trace in minute detail what your code does and compare with what it should do. Sometimes there's no other way to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add:

```
swap_numbers(an_array[from], an_array[right]);
```

just before

```
return right;
```

Comment: Your approach is similar to the C code on this page: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort